# Why does the DC motor stop when I put my finger in?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics

When I insert my finger into a moving motor with a wing, when my finger collides with the wing of the dc motor, the motor stops, and when I remove my finger, the motor rotates again.

What is this phenomenon called?

Why doesn't the engine wing push my finger out?

Do you need more voltage to push my finger out of the rotation radius?

Comment: Is your question about why the motor rotates again immediately, unlike for example a combustion engine?

Comment: Welcome *New contributor* molo32! Would you mind adding some additional context to your question? Perhaps a drawing or an image of the "moving motor with wing". A DC motor has maximum torque at 0 rpm so, if you've stopped it, that's the best it can do.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon has no special name, it happens when the motor is not powerful enough to cut off your finger and remain spinning. In the case of a lawn mower, the motor will be strong enough to cut off your finger if you stick it into the rotating blade. Please do not try this experiment at home!